# telerik ajax panel does not trigger AjaxLoadingPanel when tab is used

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have a Telerik Ajax Panel with a dropdownlist, a textbox (both with autopostback = true) and then another two readonly textboxes inside it. All controls are telerik controls.

The editable textbox has a serverside event TextChanged. When a user enters text and then hits return the ajaxloadingpanel is triggered (I get the spinning graphic) and once the server side code has completed the readonly textboxes are populated. When a user enters text and then hits TAB the ajaxloadingpanel is not triggered (no graphic) but eventually the readonly textboxes are populated.

How can I get the ajaxloadingpanel to trigger in both situations ie when the RETURN key or the TAB key are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to fix this by using client events on the RadAjaxManager and showing/hiding the AjaxLoadingPanel as needed.